# Calling function in a function with scapy library doesn't work. But works if not in a function

Tags: python, import, scapy

i'm trying to create a layer 2 protocole for pratice. There are my imports (in both files) :

```
from pystack.layers.ethernet import EthernetProtocol
from pystack.layers.arp import ARPProtocol
from pystack.layers.ethernet import Ether
from scapytrame import EtherData
from scapy.all import *
```

It works perfectly when i do those lines in a file (Sender.py)

```
ethData = EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9)
sendp(ethData)
print ethData.show()
```

So i receive the packet and i can see it in WireShark
But now i want to do it by using a function and this doesn't work. There is the second file :

```
def sender(frames, macSrc="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", iface="eth0") :
    i = 0
    sentBack = False
    while(i < len(frames)):

        # Sending packet
        frames[i].seq_ack = hex(i%2);
        frames[i].show()
        Scapy.sendp(frames[i])

        # Acknowledge + Next packet
        macDst = frames[i].dst
        filtre = "ether src " + macDst
        ack = sniff(iface=str(iface), filter=str(filtre), count=1, timeout=5)
        if not ack:
            sentBack = True
            continue
        ackData = EtherData(str(ack[0]))
        if int(ackData.seq_ack) == 2:
            sentBack = False
            i = i + 1
        else:
            continue

def receiver(macSrc="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", iface="eth0") :
    nextFrame = 0
    while(True):
        ack = sniff(iface=str(iface), filter=str(filtre), count=1)
        ackData = EtherData(str(ack[0]))
        if int(ackData.seq_ack) == nextFrame%2:
            ackData.show()
            sender([EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst=ackData.dst, seq_ack=2)])
            nextFrame = nextFrame + 1

frames_test = [ EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9),
            EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9),
            EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9),
            EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9),
            EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9)]

sender(frames_test)
```

Then i get an error as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ProtAckPosAndTrans.py", line 47, in <module>
    sender(frames_test)
  File "ProtAckPosAndTrans.py", line 15, in sender
    sendp(frames[i])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 259, in sendp
    __gen_send(conf.L2socket(iface=iface, *args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count, verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 234, in __gen_send
    s.send(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/supersocket.py", line 32, in send
    sx = str(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 261, in __str__
    return self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 319, in build
    p = self.do_build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 308, in do_build
    pkt = self.self_build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 299, in self_build
    p = f.addfield(self, p, val)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 70, in addfield
    return s+struct.pack(self.fmt, self.i2m(pkt,val))
struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
```

The frames[i].show() works perfectly and i also did a 'print frames[i].**class**' everything is find... So i can't get why it is not working.

I searched everywhere can't find an anwser. Thanks for answers :)

Comment: I use it to know if i have to send the packet again : if no ack (timeout) , but if it catches another Ether, which is no ack, i'll just wait for an ack again without sending the packet again.

Comment: After "if not ack:" (= timeout) i set it as True and after "if ackData.seq_ack == 2" (= being acknowledge packet).

Now i need to use it before the "sendp()" but i need it to work first :)

Comment: Ok. Does your code fail on the first iteration (i=0) ?

Comment: Yes. frames[0].show() works.
But sendp(frames[0]) crashes...

Comment: And if i put directly sendp(EtherData(src="00:21:70:a2:b7:6d", dst="d4:3d:7e:6c:66:e9", data="Kikouuu!", seq_ack=9)) it works
So i don't get it... Should i cast frames[i] even if frames[i].show() works?...

Comment: And what if you comment the line `frames[i].seq_ack = hex(i%2)` ?

Comment: That is actuallly the problem (i just find out). So i decided to go to an exclusive EtherData (x) where i change the data throw the x.seq_ack...

Not really practical through isn't it anyway to stock some instances of EtherData in a list?

Comment: It is not my area of expertise, but I find it peculiar that you have a `int` as a value for `seq_ack` when you create an `EtherData` instance and then you change it to an hexadecimal string with `frames[i].seq_ack = hex(i%2)`. This might be the issue.